# How do I make sure Spring JMS concurrently consuming messages?

Tags: spring-jms

I am Using Spring-JMS for consuming messages from the queues. I have configure concurrent consumer as 5 and max concurent consumer as 10 and then push more than 1k messages on the queue. I could see there are 5 DMLC consumer running but at a time I could see only 1 is consuming the messages and all others are in waiting state. Is there any configuration I am missing so that all 5 DMLC should start consuming the messages. 
I am following approach that is given in below link as I have multiple queues that I want to register with.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated-programmatic-registration.

Using below code to register multiple queues

```
 queues.foreach( queue -> {
     SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
            endpoint.setId("myJmsEndpoint"+counter++);
            endpoint.setDestination(queue);
            registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint,defaultJMSListenerCOnnectionFactory);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActiveMQ, there is a prefetch setting that defaults to 1k.  This means that messages will be pushed to the consumers 1k at a time. You can add:

```
?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1
```

to your client broker URL.  This will disable the prefetching.

Comment: Yes I am using ActiveMQ. I have set Concurrent Consumer is 5 and maximum concurrent Consumer is 10. After setting above prefetchPolicy I still see 10 DMLC consumer but only one in consuming message at a time, Others consumers are in waiting state only. So looks like PrefetchPolicy doesn't worked.